# Check all checkboxes on spawned page template

Tags: javascript, forms, templates, pdf, checkbox

I have created a form with page templates that are spawned when a user selects a checkbox on the form.
One of the page templates has a list of checkboxes, followed by 'select all' checkbox. When this is checked, all of the checkboxes automatically check.
This works fine on the page template, but when the template is spawned, the 'link' between the 'select all' checkbox is broken and no other checkboxes are selected.
This is the javascript that I have so far:

```
if(event.target.isBoxChecked(0))
{// Perform actions when checked
   this.getField(“A”).checkThisBox(0,true);
   this.getField(“B”).checkThisBox(0,true);        this.getField(“C”).checkThisBox(0,true);        this.getField(“D”).checkThisBox(0,true);        this.getField(“E”).checkThisBox(0,true);        this.getField(“F”).checkThisBox(0,true);        this.getField(“G”).checkThisBox(0,true);     }
else
{// Perform actions when unchecked
   this.getField(“A”).checkThisBox(0,false);
   this.getField(“B”).checkThisBox(0,false);        this.getField(“C”).checkThisBox(0,false);        this.getField(“D”).checkThisBox(0,false);        this.getField(“E”).checkThisBox(0,false);        this.getField(“F”).checkThisBox(0,false);        this.getField(“G”).checkThisBox(0,false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your input.
I found a thread which works perfectly:

```
var cPreFix = "";
// get prefix elements for spawned pages;
var aFieldName = event.target.name.split(".");
if(aFieldName.length > 2)
{
// first 2 elements of name array makeup the prefix for fields on a spawned page;
cPreFix = aFieldName[0] + "." + aFieldName[1] + ".";
}
//if/else conditional statement
if(event.target.isBoxChecked(0))
{// Perform actions when checked
  this.getField(cPreFix +"Option1").checkThisBox(0,true);
  this.getField(cPreFix +"Option2").checkThisBox(0,true); 
  this.getField(cPreFix +"Option3").checkThisBox(0,true); 
else
{// Perform actions when unchecked
  this.getField(cPreFix +"Option1").checkThisBox(0,false);
  this.getField(cPreFix +"Option2").checkThisBox(0,false); 
  this.getField(cPreFix +"Option3").checkThisBox(0,false);
}
```

Thanks to gkaiseril from the adobe community forums :
acrobat/how-do-i-have-calculated-scripts-adjust-when-i-spawn-a-new-page-from-a-template/
[https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat/how-do-i-have-calculated-scripts-adjust-when-i-spawn-a-new-page-from-a-template/m-p/9902135?page=1]